# How to create a new environment with \begin{frame}\begin{itemize}

Tags: beamer, environments

In order to save some typing, I tried to create a new environment with some commands I use very often. But LaTeX does not like them, and keep me throwing errors at my head when I use them.

Here is a minimal example of the failing code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{default}

\newenvironment{iframe}[1]{
  \begin{frame}{#1}
    \begin{itemize}
}{
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{iframe}{grml}
    \item<1-> Foo
    \item<2-> Bar
\end{iframe}

\end{document}
```

I just wanted to have an environment which creates a new frame and puts me into an `itemize` environment, but instead throw the following error message at me:

```
Runaway argument?
\let \AtEndDocument \@firstofone \@enddocumenthook \@checkend {docume\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> qt

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on qt.log.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out why using internal commands (`\itemize` and `\enditemize`) works but using normal environment commands doesn't work. Anyway, this is possibly what you want

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{default}

\newenvironment{iframe}[1]{
  \begin{frame}{#1}
    \itemize
}{
    \enditemize
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{iframe}{grml}
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
    \item Baz
\end{iframe}

\end{document}
```

[image]